# htaccess works, but SEO checkers say 404

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm a bit confused on how htaccess is working.

I have this rule (as part of a larger set) and it works fine in the browser:

```
RewriteRule ^steamplay/$ steamplay.php [N,NC,QSA]
```

So it's correctly showing "/steamplay/" in the URL and displaying steamplay.php contents as expected.

However, any SEO checker reports that it's a 404. What would cause that?

Full rules:

```
Options +SymLinksifOwnerMatch

  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteBase /

  ErrorDocument 401 default
  ErrorDocument 403 default
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?module=404
  ErrorDocument 500 /down.html
  
  #fonts
  AddType application/font-sfnt            otf ttf
  AddType application/font-woff            woff
  AddType application/font-woff2           woff2
  AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject    eot

  # BEGIN EXPIRES
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/webp "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 year" 
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/font-sfnt "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
# END EXPIRES

# Extra Security Headers

<IfModule mod_headers.c>

    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"

    Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN

    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff

</IfModule>
  
  RewriteRule ^image_prox/([%\w\.-_]*)$ /includes/image_proxy.php?url=$1 [N,NC]

  RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]

  RewriteRule ^home/$ /index.php?module=home [N]

  RewriteRule ^calendar/$ /index.php?module=calendar [N]

  RewriteRule ^mailinglist/$ /index.php?module=mailing_list [N]

  RewriteRule ^articles/$ /index.php?module=home [N]

  RewriteRule ^all-articles/$ /index.php?module=home&displayall [N,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^all-articles/page\=([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?module=home&page=$1&displayall [N]

  RewriteRule ^admin/$ /index.php?module=home [N]

  RewriteRule ^latest-comments/$ /index.php?module=comments_latest [N]

  RewriteRule ^latest-comments/page=([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?module=comments_latest&page=$1 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^home/banned/$ /index.php?module=home&message=banned [N]

  RewriteRule ^irc/$ /index.php?module=irc [N]

  RewriteRule ^register/$ /index.php?module=register [N]

  RewriteRule ^about-us/$ /index.php?module=about_us [N]

  RewriteRule ^private-messages/$ /index.php?module=messages [N]

  RewriteRule ^submit-article/$ /index.php?module=submit_article&view=Submit [N]

  RewriteRule ^submit-article/error\=(.+?)?$ /index.php?module=submit_article&view=Submit&error=$1 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^contact-us/$ /index.php?module=contact [N]

  RewriteRule ^email-us/$ /index.php?module=email_us [N]

  RewriteRule ^support-us/$ /index.php?module=support_us [N]

  RewriteRule ^community/$ /index.php?module=community [N]

  RewriteRule ^articles/$ /index.php?module=home [N]

  RewriteRule ^articles/(.+?)\.([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?module=articles_full&title=$1&aid=$2 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?module=articles_full&aid=$1 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^articles/(.+?)\.([0-9]+)/error=(.+?)/?$ /index.php?module=articles_full&aid=$2&title=$1&error=$3 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^articles/(.+?)\.([0-9]+)/page\=([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?module=articles_full&aid=$2&title=$1&page=$3 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^articles/(.+?)\.([0-9]+)/comment_id\=([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?module=articles_full&aid=$2&title=$1&comment_id=$3 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^articles/(.+?)\.([0-9]+)/article_page\=([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?module=articles_full&aid=$2&title=$1&article_page=$3 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^home/page\=([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?module=home&page=$1 [N]

  RewriteRule ^private-messages/page\=([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?module=messages&page=$1 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^private-messages/compose/(\d+)*/$ /index.php?module=messages&view=compose [N]

  RewriteRule ^private-messages/compose/user\=([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?module=messages&view=compose&user=$1 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^private-messages/([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?module=messages&view=message&id=$1 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^private-messages/([0-9]+)/page\=([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?module=messages&view=message&id=$1&page=$2 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^profiles/([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?module=profile&user_id=$1 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^profiles/([0-9]+)/comments/$ /index.php?module=profile&view=more-comments&user_id=$1 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^profiles/([0-9]+)/comments/page\=([0-9]+)$ /index.php?module=profile&view=more-comments&user_id=$1&page=$2 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^users/statistics/$ /index.php?module=statistics [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^users/statistics/statid=([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?module=statistics&statid=$1&act=pick [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^articles/category/(.+?)/page\=([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?module=articles&view=cat&catid=$1&page=$2 [N,NC,QSA,B]

  RewriteRule ^articles/category/(.+?)/$ /index.php?module=articles&view=cat&catid=$1 [N,NC,QSA,B]

  RewriteRule ^itemdb/([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?module=items_database&view=item&id=$1 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^itemdb/developer/([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?module=items_database&view=developer&id=$1 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^itemdb/anticheats/([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?module=items_database&view=anticheats&id=$1 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^steam-tracker/$ /index.php?module=steam_linux_share [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^steamplay/$ steamplay.php [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^steamplay/reports/([0-9]+)/$ steamplay_reports.php?id=$1 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^steamplay/reports/([0-9]+)/page=([0-9]+)/$ steamplay_reports.php?id=$1&page=$2 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^db/$ itemdb.php [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^free-games/$ free_games.php [N]

  RewriteRule ^itemdb/steamid/([0-9]+)/$ itemdb.php?steamid=$1 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^sales/page=([0-9]+)/$ /sales.php?page=$1 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^sales/([0-9]+)/$ /sales.php?sale_id=$1 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^sales/message=(.+?)/?$ /sales.php?message=$1 [N,NC,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^sales/$ sales.php [N]

  Redirect 301 /podcast_rss_ogg.php /podcast_rss.php?format=ogg

  # force trailing slash
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$        /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
  
  # if requested url does not exist pass it as path info to index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: You need to check the HTTP response code. Maybe your server is sending a 404 status instead of 200 OK? _Aside:_ You should be using the `L` flag, not `N` on all these directives.

Comment: What "SEO checkers" have you actually tried?  If you use [curl](https://curl.se) from the command line like `curl --head https://example.com/steamplay` what does it show?

Comment: @MrWhite OMG you're right, even the PHP page directly is giving a 404. Now I know where to look!

Comment: Why do they need L instead of N?

Comment: The `N` flag causes the ruleset to start over from the top, passing the output of the last rule directly back to the rewrite engine - this is used to create "loops" when you need to repeat the same task multiple times (eg. search and replace). Fortunately, in your case, the rewritten URL doesn't match any of the other rules (at least not so far as I can see with a quick glance) so you don't get stuck in a loop. What you really need is for processing to _stop_, so you should be using `L` (`last`) (or `END`).

Comment: I'm curious how you came to be using the `N` flag? You are using the `L` flag on a couple of your rewrites.

Comment: @MrWhite the htaccess is super old, and originally done by someone else who I guess didn't quite do it right. Thanks again for the tips, really helped!